# ASP.NET how to check which button was clicked

Tags: asp.net

Here's the deal, I making a website that sells some products and according to how much products I have the ammount of buttons changes too.

For example if I have 5 products I will have 5 buttons, something like this:
[image: Example]

What I want to do is when a button is clicked I want to take the item name and save it (in a session) so I can use this information on a different page (the code behind is in C#).

How can I do this?

Comment: All buttons share the same handler?

Comment: @TimSchmelter What do you mean by "handler"? id? if so I can make it happed.